# What's the biggest fixed point number that can be expressed in 8 bits?

Tags: bit, vivado, fixed-point, vivado-hls

Suppose an 8-bit fixed point number x, where 7 bits are allocated to the fractional part and 1 bit to the integer part. How can I calculate the biggest possible number that can be expressed using this Q8.1 configuration? Is there a proper method to perform these calculations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic." In fixed-point computing it is often necessary to convert a value to a different scaling factor." Seems that it depends on the scaling factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest fixed-point number will always have the same binary value as the largest integer value. If your fixed-point number is unsigned then its largest binary value is 11111111 (decimal 255). The equivalent decimal fixed-point value is just this decimal integer value divided by 2^7, or 1.9921875